# Lightswitch choice list

Tags: list, visual-studio-lightswitch

When we configure a field as a choice list and set up some initial values, where are they stored? I understand we could configure them as a dynamic list by using a separate table. I am trying to understand what happens with the static list.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Choice list data gets stored in the *lsml* file, which is why it's only a reasonable option for **very** static data.

To add/delete values, the developer has to make the change & redeploy the entire applictaion.

Does that help with what you were wanting to knmow?